# Parse iOS p12 certificate with a password

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I understand that the documentation/tutorial from Parse for iOS push notification says to create a p12 certificate *without* a password, however I'm dealing with a big enterprise client who is providing their own p12 certificate and they are insisting that they can only provide me one that's password protected.

So is there any possible way to use one with a password? I'm still trying to push back on the client but I'm checking every possible angle.  I really don't want to roll my own server and I like Parse and want to use them

thanks

Comment: You should drop the idea of using parse for push notification then.

Comment: Or you take the encrypted one that the client provided (if they can only provide *with* password)  and use the password to create an unprotected one... No-one will ever know (except all of _us_) 

Comment: I kinda like @Julian 's idea too :D :D

Comment: I got the client to comply and send me a cert without a password in the end